# Selecting using Sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to display the names and salaries of staff due to have a birthday in 30 days but I keep getting the error; `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

```
SELECT Name, Salary  
FROM STAFF  
WHERE DOB > trunc(SYSDATE) + DAYS '30';
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 30 days implies you actually want 1 month? In which case you might want the `add_months` function...

Comment: Read some basics http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/377/Others/tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The query can be written as below-

```
SELECT Name, Salary  
FROM STAFF  
WHERE to_date(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')||to_char(DOB,'MMDD'),'YYYYMMDD')  > trunc(sysdate+30);
```

To get the salaries of employees whose birthday is within the next thirty days use -

```
SELECT Name, Salary  
FROM STAFF  
WHERE to_date(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')||to_char(DOB,'MMDD'),'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) AND trunc(sysdate+30);
```

`+30` adds thirty days by default to a date.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
SELECT Name, Salary
  FROM STAFF
  WHERE TO_DATE( TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || TO_CHAR(DOB, 'MMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD' )
          BETWEEN (TRUNC(SYDATE) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 30);
```

Two assumptions: date of birth isn't this year, and you want anything within the next 30 days, not just 30 days out. TRUNC to get rid of time components on dates if they exist.

And the syntax for adding an interval is:

```
dob + interval '1' days
```